# generate mixed products and blog posts section Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to make a mixed section of products and blog posts. My logic is the following:

- get array with all products
- get array with all blog posts
- merge the two arrays following a pattern (3 products - 2 posts)
- display data

I'm having trouble with the merge of the two arrays. I get the error message "argument is not an array element".

```
{% capture product_list %}
  {% for product in collection.products%}
    {{product.title}}|{{product.url}}|{{product.description}}| 
    {{product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}
    {% if forloop.last == false %}::{% endif%}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% capture blog_list %}
  {% for blog in blog.articles%}
    {{blog.title}}|{{blog.url}}
    {% if forloop.last == false %}::{% endif%}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign plants = product.list | concat: blog.list %}

{{ plants | join: ", " }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are in Shopify front-end request sense. If you are on a product page ie: /products, Shopify ensures you have a valid product. In your case, your code only works as you iterate a collection for products, so we assume you're on a collection page. If you are on a blog page, you get a blog object but no product or collections.

So your trouble stems from that. Take a look at the **Global Objects** in Shopify and you can see that you can access any 20 products using all_products, any blog, and any articles, using their handles. Adjust your code to that.